# Retrieve firebase data in javascript returns object object

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to retrieve some data from firebase using javascript. I keep getting the Object Object output. here is my code:

```
var notesRef = database.ref('elimio/users/' + userId + '/my-notes');
  notesRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  var returnArr = [];
  var childData = snapshot.val();
  returnArr.push(childData)
  res.render('head', {users:user.displayName, notes:childData});
});
```

and this is how I try to retrieve in client page:

```
<p><%= notes %></p>
```

.Any help please?

Comment: console the output of `childData` that you are getting from the snapshot

Comment: @Himanshu the log has got all the posts,,,,  why do you think its not working on the front end?

Comment: yes will post the output and then take the value inside that object to print on the template. either using map to loop over the objects. `notes` contains an object itself. you should print the values inside the object.

Comment: and also the posts have the unique key i.e '' },
  '-LIfZ5sIjAPJT-NDfVkq':
   { notes: '

Comment: yes it definitely will have that's how firebase save the data using timestamps for keys. you should loop over the data to print each record on the ejs template

Comment: i dont think i understand how to do it..how do i get the note from this 'childData' object..headstart kindly

Comment: kindly post the testing output of console for childata object and I will do that. One question also you are using ejs if I am not wrong.

Comment: the output is like so: 'unique-key' { notes: "xxxxxxxxxx"} yes express js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is printing the object because the object is assigned inside node when creating a variable. For getting the value stored inside the object returned from firebase. you should loop over it.

```
<%Object.keys(notes).forEach(function(key){%>
   <li>the value is: <%=notes[key].notes %></li>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: the output is a list of i think the total number of posts like this : "the value is: [object Object]"

Comment: yes sir it will be I have given you an example how it should be done. You have create a nested for. That's why I have asked you to provide a sample of data. I cannot create an answer with exact output. I just wants know how nested your object is so that I can get exact value from it

Comment: here is a sample :   '-LIfZm2ppi4vnPTQWfLo': { notes: 'hey hey' },
  '-LIfZmFrf_K_t-cPN1rh': { notes: 'hey hey' },
  '-LIfZmT5HJJnG-MFaMP6': { notes: 'hey hey' },
  '-LIfZmtmmcLEntccul9Y': { notes: 'hey hey' },
  '-LIfZmw9-LprYlFJ6hdl': { notes: 'hey hey' },
  '-LIfZn7jfo494q6yH_jZ': { notes: 'hey hey' },
  '-LIfZnB1DW9Lcdfby5Vn': { notes: 'hey hey' },

Comment: Please check updated answer for getting the value of object use `.` dot notation